# parse using regex and print the line

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex which is used to print the lines of file within a specified range.

Eg:

```
my _car_(10)
skoda
audi

my home
good

my _car_(11)
benz
```

outputs as:

```
(10)
skoda
audi
(11)
benz
```

EXPECTED:(I need to print the line `my _car_` lines also)

```
my _car_(10)
skoda
audi
my _car_(11)
benz
```

cODING:

```
import re
with open("in1.txt") as f:
   lines = f.read()
   m = re.findall(r'(?s)my _car_\s*(.*?)my', lines)
   for i in m:
       print i
```

Please help me to fix it,answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include `my _car_`, simply move the opening parenthesis of the capture group.

But that raises a second problem. You are including the subsequent "my" in the result. Use lookahead `(?=...)` to avoid capturing it.

But that raises yet another problem. The final car doesn't have a trailing `my`. So we search for end-of-string also.

Final result:

```
m = re.findall(r'(?s)(my _car_\s*.*?)(?=my|$)', lines)
```

Unrelated to the regular expression search, the use of `print` introduces an extra line between items. We can replace `print` with `os.write()`, or we can use a trailing `,` to avoid the extra lines.

Program:

```
import re
with open("in1.txt") as f:
   lines = f.read()
   m = re.findall(r'(?s)(my _car_\s*.*?)(?=my|$)', lines)
   for i in m:
       print i,
```

Result:

```
$ python in1.py 
my _car_(10)
skoda
audi

my _car_(11)
benz
```

Comment: That would output `my _car_(10)\nskoda\naudi` (with actual newlines).

Comment: Right. That is what was asked for.

Comment: Umm, shouldn't it also include `my _car_(11)\nbenz`?

Comment: It does include the "benz" lines. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: @Robᵩ Why there is some blank lines exists?

Comment: @Robᵩ it's not with the print statement. The problem is in your regex see http://regex101.com/r/lD8nJ2/3

Comment: no problem, just change your regex to `(?s)my _car_.*?(?=\n\n|$)`, http://regex101.com/r/lD8nJ2/5

Comment: @Robᵩ ,please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555155/delete-regex-matching-part-of-file?noredirect=1#comment39905206_25555155

Answer (score 1):

Just try the below code which uses a negative lookahead and a positive lookahead.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """my _car_(10)
... skoda
... audi
... 
... my home
... good
... 
... my _car_(11)
... benz"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'my\s*_car_(?:(?!\n\n).)*(?=\n\n|$)', s, re.DOTALL)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
my _car_(10)
skoda
audi
my _car_(11)
benz
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lD8nJ2/4)

**Explanation:**

- `my\s*_car_` Matches the string `my` followed by zero or more spaces and again followed by the string `_car_`.
- `(?:(?!\n\n).)*` Matches any character but not of `\n\n` zero or more times.
- `(?=\n\n|$)` Lookahead  asserts that what follows must be `\n\n`(ie, a blank line) or the line end `$`

Comment: That negative lookahead is superfluous. You're already looking ahead for two consecutive newlines.

Comment: no, try without the negative lookahead in the demo site.

Comment: could u help me on how to delete the regex matching part and write to a file?

Comment: @Chaeltrims sorry i don't know , maybe you could ask it as an another question or seek some others for help. I think Rob should know that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this is my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555155/delete-regex-matching-part-of-file?noredirect=1#comment39905206_25555155 ,hope u could answer it!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to extend your capture group:

from this

`m = re.findall(r'(?s)my _car_\s*(.*?)my', lines)`

to this

`m = re.findall(r'(?s)(my _car_\s*.*?)my', lines)`

should do.

But according to your regex you must have a `my` after the last value to capture untill it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookahead to achieve this:

```
(?s)(my _car_\s*.*?)(?=(?:\n{2}|\Z))
```

`(?=(?:\n{2}|\Z))` asserts that the part after `_car_` is followed by either 2 newline characters or the end of the string (`\Z`).

Test:

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('in1.txt') as f:
...     lines = f.read()
...     m = re.findall(r'(?s)(my _car_\s*.*?)(?=(?:\n{2}|\Z))', lines)
...     for i in m:
...             print i
... 
my _car_(10)
skoda
audi
my _car_(11)
benz
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression seems unnecessary, try:

```
cars = False
with open("in1.txt") as f:
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        if line.startswith('my _car_'):
            print line
            cars = True
        elif line.startswith('my'):
            cars = False
        elif cars and line:
            print line
```

Which will output:

```
my _car_(10)
skoda
audi
my _car_(11)
benz
```