# Delete regex matching part of file

Tags: python, regex

I have a file ,and i need to delete the regex matching part and write remaining lines to a file.

Regex matching Code to delete file:

```
import re
with open("in1.txt") as f:
   lines = f.read()
   m = re.findall(r'(?s)(my _car_\s*.*?)my', lines)
```

Input file:

```
my _car_(10)
   skoda
  audi

my home
 good

my _car_(11)
 benz
```

Expected output:

```
my home
 good
```

Please help me to fix it,answers will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse using regex and print the line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553575/parse-using-regex-and-print-the-line)

Comment: To clarify: you are trying to remove all lines that start with a space which follow a line matching the regex?

Comment: no,i need to blindly remove lines matching regex alone

Comment: @Dalor its not a dupe of that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
with open("in1.txt") as f:
   lines = f.read()
   m = re.sub(r'(?s)my _car_.*?(?=my|$)', '', lines)
   m = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', m)
   print m,
```

Comment: its not getting deleted,please help!

Comment: You need to open the file and write the contents of 'm' to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to write the lines out, [this regex replacement](http://regex101.com/r/hW9wX1/1) may be what you're looking for

```
lines = re.sub(r'(?s)(my _car_\s*.*?)(my|$)', r'\2', lines).strip()
```

---

It sounds like you don't know how to write out to a file. To dump the text to a file called *out.txt*:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(lines)
```

Comment: i get the same` file its not deleted!